# How do I fix the "Error 403, forbidden" while calling the Microsoft Graph in a Microsoft Teams personal app via an SPFx webpart?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, spfx

I´ve built an SPFx Webpart, which requests a SharePoint list via the Microsoft Graph. It works fine in both SharePoint and as a Microsoft Teams Tab. However, when I try to run it in Teams as a personal App, I always get an error 403 forbidden.

As a debug measure, I followed a Microsoft tutorial on making a simple graph call https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-msgraph. After trying the webpart in both SharePoint and Teams again, I ran into the same issue. It works both in SharePoint and as a Teams tab, but not as a Teams personal app.

```
public render(): void {
this.context.msGraphClientFactory
  .getClient()
  .then((client: MSGraphClient): void => {
    // use MSGraphClient here
    // get information about the current user from the Microsoft Graph
    client
      .api('/me')
      .get((error, user: MicrosoftGraph.User, rawResponse?: any) => {
        console.log(user);

        this.domElement.innerHTML = `
          <div class=${styles.container}>
            <h2>${user.displayName}</h2>
          </div>
        `;

        if(error) {
          console.log("Error: ");
          console.log(error);
        }

    });
  });
}
```

As the last test, I downloaded an already made and functioning project which requests data via the Microsoft Graph https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-teams-personal-app-settings, and it returned the same error.

Additionally, the global admins in our tenant have no issue using these apps as a Microsoft Teams personal App. The problem only occurs for standard users.

Does anyone know why this web part won't work as a personal app but anywhere else, and also how to fix this issue?

**18.11.2020: Quick update about the problem**: After an admin granted all the permissions again, all the apps now works in the teams web client as a personal app, but still not in the desktop app as a personal app.

**Another update about the problem**: I tried installing Teams in Linux as a test, and as it turned out, all the apps work as Teams personal apps there.

Comment: Do you grant delegation permission for the app and grant admin consent for that permission?

Comment: Yes, the global admins in our tenant granted them for every user. But the app still returns the same error when used as a Teams personal app.

Comment: @JBLConsult Are you still facing the issue? If so please share the requestid and timestamp for the failed request and the whole error response.

Comment: @Shiva-MSFTIdentity, yes, I'm still facing the issue. The response I'm getting from the server is: 
{"odata.error":{"code":"-2147024891, System.UnauthorizedAccessException","message":{"lang":"de-DE","value":"Zugriff verweigert. Sie haben keine Berechtigung, diesen Vorgang auszuf\u00fchren oder auf diese Ressource zuzugreifen."}}}
The request ID is: 62358e9f-c0aa-2000-8af6-6ac1e0ad3879
And the timestamp is: Mon, 16 Nov 2020 13:05:47 GMT
I hope these are the information you need.

Comment: The Requestid and timestamp that you gave is not valid. Please give a fresh requestid, timestamp for the failed http call.

Comment: I just did the request again and looked up the data in the teams developer tools. For the failed request, the request-id is f4d58e9f-10a2-2000-8af6-62e099731f3c and the timestamp (I guess its the header variable called Date) is Wed, 18 Nov 2020 11:51:57 GMT.

Comment: Please check the access token and the context whether it has the required permissions in [JWT site](https://jwt.ms).

Comment: Im sorry, but I wasn’t able to find any access token. I looked at the request headers, the source code and in Azure and I wasn’t able to find any belonging to the SOFx solution. Could you please specify where I can get the access token?

Comment: Please check if you have "webApplicationInfo" added in manifest
"webApplicationInfo": {​​​​
    "id": "00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000",
    "resource": "add your domain - https://??????.sharepoint.com"
  }​​​​
Keep the ID same - this is for SharePoint

Comment: Hello VaraPrasad, thank you for the suggestion. In which of the manifests do I have to add this? The Manifest in the Add-In itself, the manifest to deploy the solution to teams or the manifest for the SharePoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application Principal in Azure?

Comment: You need to add to the Manifest in the Add-In itself, the manifest to deploy the solution to teams

Comment: Well, I looked it up and I noticed the "webApplicationInfo" was already there. I tried as values for the "resource" parameter both the value I got of the Microsoft docs ({teamSiteDomain}) and I hardcoded out tenant name there, but in both cases, I ran into the same issue

Comment: @JBLConsult Does your issue got resolved?

Answer (score 0):

I think is has something to do with the "SharePoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application Principal".

1. Go to https://portal.azure.com
2. Open your Azure AD and goto "App registrations" (on the left)
3. You should be able to find "SharePoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application Principal" under "All applications"
   [image]
4. Open this application and go to "Expose an API" (on the left)
5. Add a client application with the ID "00000003-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000" and check "https://microsoft.spfx3rdparty.com/user_impersonation"
   [image]

Comment: Thank you for your help there RoelVB. I checked the Azure AD, but unfortunately, the client application with this ID was already there and all permissions were granted. Still, none of the apps is working as a Teams personal app.

Comment: Any solution for this issue? I have tried all the different options that are suggested on the net, but I couldn't find any solution.