# 403(Forbidden) Invalid permission error in my SPFx web part when trying to access SharePointSiteUsageDetail with MSGraph

Tags: permissions, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, spfx

I can GET data from this url in Graph Explorer,but when I try in my SPFx solution it gives me an 403(Forbidden) error:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/reports/getSharePointSiteUsageDetail(period='D30')?$format=application/json
```

Error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GirBw.png)

In the package-solution.json file,I set these permissions:

```
"webApiPermissionRequests": [                                
      {"resource": "Microsoft Graph","scope":"User.ReadBasic.All"},
      {"resource": "Microsoft Graph","scope": "sites.Read.All"},
      {"resource": "Microsoft Graph","scope": "Reports.Read.All"}]
```

the code fetching data with MS Graph:

```
public GetUsageData = (): void => {
    this.props.context.msGraphClientFactory
      .getClient()
      .then((msGraphClient: MSGraphClient) => {
        const period = 7;
        msGraphClient
          .api(
            "reports/getSharePointSiteUsagePages(period='D" +
              period +
              "')?$format=application/json"
          )
          .version("v1.0")
          .get((err, report: any, res: any) => {
            if (err) {
              console.log("Error occured from usage", err);
            }
            console.log("Error occured usage data", err);
            console.log("Response usage data", res);
            res.value.map((result) => {
              this.allUsage.push({
                storageUsedInBytes: result.storageUsedInBytes,
                storageAllocatedInBytes: result.storageAllocatedInBytes,
              });
            });
            this.setState({ usageDataState: this.allUsage });
          });
      });
```

I have set the required Report.Read.All permission to "SharePoint Online Client Extensibility Web Application Principal":
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HuXAT.png)

I approved the permissions in my sharePoint admin center:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPafJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Office 365 usage reports are protected by both permissions and azure ad roles and supports two [types of authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/reportroot-authorization#assign-azure-ad-roles-to-users) including user delegated.
2. Reports.Read.All  `delegated permission` is required when you sign in with work or school account [to >  getSharePointSiteUsageDetail](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getsharepointsiteusagedetail?view=graph-rest-1.0) .Then the user consent is also needed along with admin consent ,where user must have **one of** the following roles:

> Company Administrator, Exchange Administrator, SharePoint
> Administrator, Lync Administrator, Teams Service Administrator, Teams
> Communications Administrator, Global Reader, Usage Summary Reports
> Reader, or Reports Reader. The Global Reader and Usage Summary Reports
> Reader roles will only have access to tenant-level data, without
> visibility into detailed metrics., To consent on behalf of user, you
> need to have

i.e; the user must be a member of an Azure AD limited administrator role.

[image]

3. MSGraphClient  uses `implicit authentication access token.` Check the access token after Decoding in https://jwt.ms .It may not have had the ["wids" claim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/access-tokens#payload-claims) ( which Denotes the tenant-wide roles assigned to this user, through the groupMembershipClaims property of the application manifest. ).This claim which lists which Azure AD roles are assigned to the delegated user .And so , if not present states it doesn’t have permissions.

**Work around:**

The permissions requested in the SPFx package need to be granted by a SharePoint Admin **explicitly**. Even the ones which do not need an admin consent .
This is so that all permission scopes allowed to be consumed from SPFx customisations have to go through Admin approval. So **Admin must [grant the permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/troubleshoot/administration/access-denied-or-need-permission-error-sharepoint-online-or-onedrive-for-business#resolution-option-2-select-the-most-relevant-option-and-follow-the-steps-to-fix-the-issue) again.**

By default if no permissions are granted, the only available permissions scope is user_impersonation which allows you to get limited information from the Graph.

Please refer these links for more details:

1. [available-permission-scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-msgraph#available-permission-scopes)
2. [spfx/use-aadhttpclient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/use-aadhttpclient)
3. [Calling Microsoft Graph with Delegated Implicit Authentication(briantjackett.com)](https://briantjackett.com/2020/07/13/calling-microsoft-graph-endpoint-with-delegated-implicit-authentication-does-not-include-azure-ad-roles/)
4. [sharepoint - "Error 403, forbidden" while calling the Microsoft Graph -SPFx webpart? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64645814/how-do-i-fix-the-error-403-forbidden-while-calling-the-microsoft-graph-in-a-m)